# $watch and object array

Tags: angularjs, watch

I was looking online but was unable to turn up anything on it. Does anyone know if there is anyway to have $watch return only the object which had one of its properties change.

Currently having it watch an array of objects so that when a specific property changes it then updates another array's object. Right now i'm iterating through the old and new arrays that $watch passes back and checking to see what changed. Seems wasteful and with the large arrays of data i'm expecting not something i'd prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From AngularJS [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

`$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]):`

- `watchExpression` - expression that is evaluated on each $digest cycle. A change in the return value triggers a call to the listener
- `listener` - callback called whenever the value of watchExpression changes; `function(newVal, oldVal, scope)`; params:

  - `newVal` contains the current value of the watchExpression
  - `oldVal` contains the previous value of the watchExpression
  - `scope` refers to the current scope
- `objectEquality` - compare for object equality using angular.equals instead of comparing for reference equality

So you could pass in your function `newVal` and `oldVal` params and check what object from array is popped up/pushe into.

Hope that helps

Comment: yea i was looking at those params but was hoping there might be one missing.

Answer (score 0):

try with this trick.

```
$scope.$watch('myArray.length', function(){
  console.log("My array has changed",$scope.myArray);
});
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback. Its not watching for a new object to be inserted but rather for one of the objects to have one of it's properties updated i.e 

[{val: 1},{val: 1}] and the first object get's its val updated to 2. I would have a watch for watch to return the index of the object that got updated